# Reusabilty: how to use same list items at different places in a web page

Tags: javascript, html

i want to use a set of 100 list items in a home page and also in 2 different dialog boxes. I guess, writing same set of code will be foolish. so how can i use the same set at 3 different places in a web page

Answer (score 0):

I would use jQuery (or some other client side library) to clone the items, and append them to each `<select>` tag.  If you need help with that, let me know.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this snippet to clone HTML,

```
  <script>
      (function(){
        $(document).ready(function(){

            $("#listA").clone().appendTo("#dialogueBox1");
            $("#listA").clone().appendTo("#dialogueBox2");

         })
       })();
   </script>
```

where listA being the id of the "ul" or "ol" element.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a pure HTML5 solution this could be interesting... using the `datalist` element - support for this *(at the moment)* will be very limited however:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/datalist

*(sourced from the link above)*

```
<datalist id="browsers">
  <option value="Chrome">
  <option value="Firefox">
  <option value="Internet Explorer">
  <option value="Opera">
  <option value="Safari">
</datalist>

<input class="one" list="browsers" />
<input class="two" list="browsers" />
<input class="three" list="browsers" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I would store the list in a json file: list.json

```
{
  list: [element0, element1, ..., element99]
}
```

Then retrieve the elements via ajax, using jQuery, for example:

```
/**
 * Replaces the element's content with the list of items.
 */
function setList(element) {
  $.getJson(listJsonURL, function (data) {
    var list = "<ul>";
    for (var i = 0, len = data.list.length; i<len; i++) {
      list += "\n  <li>" + data.list[i] + "</li>";
    }
    list += "\n</ul>";
    $(element).html(list);
  });
}
```

WARNING: Untested code.